# Web Api paramater passed through Angular is null

Tags: .net, angular

So I am trying to pass a string to my Web Api through a put call in an Angular service. The service actually calls the method on the Web Api side, but the parameter always comes through null. Can someone shed a bit of light, thanks.

Here is what the code looks like:

Web Api: (the breakpoint is set on the first parenthesis)

```
public void Put([FromBody]string userId)
{


}
```

Angular :

```
 UpdateManagerEmail(userId){
    userId = '577f1e6e-146d-49f1-a354-b31349e7cb49';
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    this._http.put('http://localhost:428/api/User', {
        userId : userId
    }).subscribe(returnVal => {
      console.log('returned');
    });
  }
```

Comment: Do you see the parameter being sent in your request within network tab of developer tools?

Comment: I can see it in the Request payload

Comment: Have you tried removing [FromBody] ?

Comment: without FromBody, it controller isn't called

Comment: have you tried wrapping the string in quotes?  `this._http.put('http://localhost:428/api/User', '"' +
        userId + '"')` OR setting a variable `var data = userId` and just passing data into the put method?  `this._http.put('http://localhost:428/api/User', data)`

Comment: I switched the string value in my controller to dynamic, and now it is being passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your backend to find userId in the request body you have send it needs to be the only value in there. You should change the `content-type` to: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8` and send the data without an key.

Remark on the docs:

> Before sending a simple type, consider wrapping the value in a complex type instead. This gives you the benefits of model validation on the server side, and makes it easier to extend your model if needed.

Source: [Sending simple types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-1#sending-simple-types)

Also, [this blog](https://blog.codenamed.nl/2015/05/12/why-your-frombody-parameter-is-always-null/) explains it better than I do.